Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileSdkVersion()'
Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileSdkVersion()'

Possible causes:

Your project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).

Upgrade plugin to version 8.3.1 and sync project
Open Gradle wrapper file
Apply Gradle plugin


I did everything that is mentioned but still not working. Provide Suggestions

Please provide more details, especially the section of your gradle config file that contains the term compileSdkVersion(). Please edit your question and include this info and the file name.
